# Positioning my main nav below my centred logo. Image included

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, nav

Hi I would like to edit my css making my main nav go below my logo which will be centered.

#### It looks like this right now

[image: This is how it looks like right now this]

#### I want it to look like this

[image: this is how I wang it to be.]

This is what my css looks like. Thank you very much for any help I can get

```
/* -- header layout -- */
    #masthead .row {
      height: 100%; }

#masthead .header-container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }

#masthead .left-links {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; }

#masthead .right-links {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; }

#masthead .left-links > ul {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px; }

#masthead .right-links > ul {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 15px; }

/* -- sticky header -- **/
#masthead.stuck {
  opacity: 0.95;
  position: fixed;
  top: -200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }

#masthead.stuck:hover {
  opacity: 1; }

#masthead.stuck.move_down {
  height: 70px;
  top: 0; }

#masthead.stuck.move_down .catalog-mode-header, #masthead.stuck.move_down .left-links > ul, #masthead.stuck.move_down .right-links > ul,
#masthead.stuck.move_down #logo a {
  padding: 0 !important; }

#masthead.stuck.move_down #logo a {
  float: none; }

#masthead.stuck.move_up {
  top: -300px; }

/* -- boxed header style --*/
.boxed #masthead {
  max-width: 71.25em;
  width: 100%;
  left: auto;
  right: auto; }

.boxed #masthead.stuck {
  left: auto;
  right: auto; }

/* -- centered logo -- */
.logo-center #masthead .left-links {
  width: 40%; }

.logo-center #masthead .right-links {
  width: 40%; }

.logo-center #masthead #logo {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center; }

.logo-center #masthead .left-links > ul {
  margin-left: 0; }

.logo-center #masthead .left-links > ul > li {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 20px; }

/* -- navigation -- */
ul.header-nav {
  margin: 0; }

ul.header-nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none; }

ul.header-nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0; }

.right-links > ul.header-nav {
  white-space: nowrap; }

.right-links > ul.header-nav > li {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: none; }
/* -- navigation -- */
ul.header-nav {
  margin: 0; }

ul.header-nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none; }

ul.header-nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0; }

.right-links > ul.header-nav {
  white-space: nowrap; }

.right-links > ul.header-nav > li {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: none; }
```

HTML

```
                <?php if($flatsome_opt['logo_position'] == 'left') : ?> 
                <div id="logo" class="logo-left">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?> - <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>" rel="home">
                        <?php if($flatsome_opt['site_logo']){
                            $site_title = esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) );
                            echo '<img src="'.$flatsome_opt['site_logo'].'" class="header_logo" alt="'.$site_title.'"/>';
                        } else {bloginfo( 'name' );}?>
                    </a>
                </div><!-- .logo -->
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="left-links">
                        <ul id="site-navigation" class="header-nav">
                            <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>

                            <?php if (!isset($flatsome_opt['search_pos']) || $flatsome_opt['search_pos'] == 'left') { ?>
                            <li class="search-dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-top-link icon-search"></a>
                                <div class="nav-dropdown">
                                    <?php get_search_form( ); ?>        
                                </div><!-- .nav-dropdown -->
                            </li><!-- .search-dropdown -->
                            <?php } ?>

                                <?php  
                                wp_nav_menu(array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                    'container'       => false,
                                    'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                                    'depth'           => 3,
                                    'walker'          => new FlatsomeNavDropdown
                                ));
                            ?>

                            <?php if (isset($flatsome_opt['search_pos']) && $flatsome_opt['search_pos'] == 'right') { ?>
                            <li class="search-dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-top-link icon-search"></a>
                                <div class="nav-dropdown">
                                    <?php get_search_form( ); ?>        
                                </div><!-- .nav-dropdown -->
                            </li><!-- .search-dropdown -->
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php else: ?>
                                <li>Define your main navigation in <b>Apperance > Menus</b></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>                             
                        </ul>
                </div><!-- .left-links -->

                <?php if($flatsome_opt['logo_position'] == 'center') { ?> 
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?> - <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>" rel="home">
                        <?php if($flatsome_opt['site_logo']){
                            $site_title = esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) );
                            echo '<img src="'.$flatsome_opt['site_logo'].'" class="header_logo" alt="'.$site_title.'"/>';
                        } else {bloginfo( 'name' );}?>
                    </a>
                </div><!-- .logo -->
                <?php } ?>

                <div class="right-links">
                    <?php if(!$flatsome_opt['catalog_mode']) { ?> 
                    <ul class="header-nav">
                        <?php if(!isset($flatsome_opt['myaccount_dropdown']) || $flatsome_opt['myaccount_dropdown']) { ?>
                        <li class="account-dropdown hide-for-small">
                            <?php
                            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?> 
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" class="nav-top-link">
                                <?php _e('My Account', 'woocommerce'); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="nav-dropdown">
                                <ul>
                                <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'my_account' ) ) : ?>
                                <?php  
                                wp_nav_menu(array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'my_account',
                                    'container'       => false,
                                    'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                                    'depth'           => 0,
                                ));
                                ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <li>Define your My Account dropdown menu in <b>Apperance > Menus</b></li>
                                <?php endif; ?> 
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- end account dropdown -->

                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" class="nav-top-link"><?php _e('Login', 'woocommerce'); ?></a>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>                      
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>


                <!-- Show mini cart if Woocommerce is activated -->
                <?php if(in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) { ?> 
                <li class="mini-cart">
                    <div class="cart-inner">
                        <?php // Edit this content in inc/template-tags.php. Its gets relpaced with Ajax! ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart-link">
                            <strong class="cart-name hide-for-small"><?php _e('Cart', 'flatsome'); ?></strong> 
                            <span class="cart-price hide-for-small">/ <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span> 
                                <!-- cart icon -->
                                <div class="cart-icon">
                                    <?php if ($flatsome_opt['custom_cart_icon']){ ?> 
                                    <div class="custom-cart-inner">
                                        <div class="custom-cart-count"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; ?></div>
                                        <img class="custom-cart-icon" src="<?php echo $flatsome_opt['custom_cart_icon']?>"/> 
                                    </div><!-- .custom-cart-inner -->
                                    <?php } else { ?> 
                                     <strong><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; ?></strong>
                                     <span class="cart-icon-handle"></span>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </div><!-- end cart icon -->
                        </a>
                        <div class="nav-dropdown">
                            <div class="nav-dropdown-inner">
                            <!-- Add a spinner before cart ajax content is loaded -->
                                <?php if ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0) {
                                    echo '<p class="empty">'.__('No products in the cart.','woocommerce').'</p>';
                                    ?> 
                                <?php } else { //add a spinner ?> 
                                    <div class="loading"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
                                <?php } ?>
                                </div><!-- nav-dropdown-innner -->
                        </div><!-- .nav-dropdown -->
                    </div><!-- .cart-inner -->
                </li><!-- .mini-cart -->
                <?php } else {echo '<li>WooCommerce not installed!</li>';} ?>
            </ul><!-- .header-nav -->
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="catalog-mode-header">
                <?php echo do_shortcode($flatsome_opt['catalog_mode_header']); ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div><!-- .right-links -->
    </div><!-- .large-12 -->
</div><!-- .row -->
```

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML also?

Comment: Show us your html code.

Comment: @Harry HTML code provided. Thank you very much

Comment: Try setting the UL display property to "Block" and removing the float property.

Comment: @StefanDunn did not move

Comment: @Abel: Sorry mate, was away. Did you manage to crack it?

Comment: @harry its ok =), I appreciate that you want to help. No I'm clueless.

Comment: Ok, let me try. It would be better, if you can give the "View Source" file rather than the one with all these PHP (or) if your files are already hosted somewhere even a link to it would do.

Comment: its hosted on www.myhouze.se. thank you Harry

Comment: You seem to have the navigation links, logo and the next item in a table-cell layout. Can your HTML mark-up be modified (or) should a solution be arrived at without touching the HTML?

Comment: The HTML can be modified =) but its important that the change doesnt result in website nav being non-responsiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things that we need to look at here, I will list them one by one.

1. The contents are currently displayed as `table-cell` with the `left-links`, `logo` and `right-links` as 3 cells (each having a unique `width`). Hence, it is not possible to achieve the expected structure without modifying the HTML also.
2. First move the entire `div` with class as `left-links` to be outside the `div` with class as `large-12 columns header-container`. Change the CSS `display` property for `left-links` to be `table-row` (consider that the same as what a `<tr>` tag would do).
3. Change the `display` for `#masthead .header-container` also to be `table-row` and `height` to 75%. So effectively the `logo` and `right-links` are part of the first row in the table and `left-links` is part of the second row.
4. Change the `width` for the `logo` to be 100% so that it takes the entire width and gets centered.
5. Finally remove `float` for `ul.header-nav li` and set the `display` for `#masthead .left-links > ul` as `table-cell`.

**Note:** This is more a hacky solution than an optimal one. But this keeps the changes to the mark-up as minimal as possible.

**Note 2:** The position of the drop-down menus are getting affected a bit due to all these changes. I will update the answer once I have a solution for that also.

Comment: thank you very much, works great besides the drop-down menu like you said

Answer (score 1):

Use margin-top and margin-left Property of css for this. Try different values of it will provide you solution.

Comment: Should I keep my width the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo on codepen, check if this help you.
If you are supporting IE7 then you need to give width to ".headerLeft". 
I have commented that code in css.

[click here for demo](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/qInFc)